# Link doesn't redirect

Tags: jsf

I like to implement a signup-page for my apptication. First of all i defined an authenticationfilter which redirects every erquest to my `login.xhtml`, when no user is set or the requestet page is not under `public`

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
HttpSession ses = req.getSession(false);
// Proceed if user is logged in or its a public page
String requestURI = req.getRequestURI();
if (requestURI.indexOf("/login.xhtml") >= 0 
    || (ses != null && ses.getAttribute("username") != null)
    || requestURI.indexOf("/public/") >= 0)
  chain.doFilter(request, response);
else {
  res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
}
```

On my login-page I have a link to /public/signup

```
<h:link value="Signup"  oncklick="/public/signup.xhtml"/>
```

When I debug I can see that see that my `requestURI` in the AuthenticationFilter is: `http://localhost:8080/appname/login.xhtml`
but I expected `http://localhost:8080/appname/public/signup.xhtml`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use outcome instead of onclick in h:link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**outcome**" attribute of `h:link` is used to specify targeted resource.

Update your `h:link` as following :

```
<h:link value="Signup"  outcome="/public/signup.xhtml"/>
```